# Is there any point to helping the rabbit?

Tags: brothers-tale-of-two-sons

In *Brothers* you come across a bunch of Rabbits at one point.

All of them are black, only one white one is between them. He obviously is an outcast because of his color (subtext, anyone?), but you can help him if you dip him into the ashes of a campfire to make him black like the others.

I did this and it appears this has nothing to do with progressing. There is a bridge nearby where you have to solve a different puzzle (involving carrying sheep, heh) to go on.

**So is there some point to this "puzzle" with the rabbits?** Is it just for fun? Or does it influence the game in any way or provide some other benefit (unlock something, I don't know).

It just seems a bit odd, because I just finished the game and there did not seem to be any other subquest like this. Of course it's possible that I just missed them.

PS: I find the moral of this puzzle rather dubious: You have to make the rabbit like all the others so that he can be happy. Pretend to be something he isn't. What advice is that supposed to give me? ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no point in helping the rabbit besides the achievement (Bunny Buddies) earned for doing so.

[image: Bunny Buddies achievement]

There are several little achievement items like this scattered throughout the game, but they don't do anything to impact the overall story.

Comment: Are you able to name the achievement? I would consider that quite a significant point being an achievement hunter.